# How can i get many headers form request with multipart/form-data

Tags: nestjs, multipartform-data, multer

I am making a system of getting file from client by multipart/form-data request. so i need two headers. one for files(type of multipart/form-data), and one for JWT(for check authorization of user)(type of string). but when i trying to send these two headers, i get an error message of "Error: Failed sending data to the peer"

So i tried to send the JWT that inside of multipart/form-data.(like the image below).

[image]

But i can't found 'x-jwt'(key of JWT) property in my request.

How can i get many headers form request with multipart/form-data.

Below code is UploadMiddleware that i am trying to get JWT from request.

And I am useing NestJs and multer to get image from client, and Insomnia to test my system.

```
import { Injectable, NestMiddleware } from '@nestjs/common';
import { NextFunction, Request, Response } from 'express';
import { JWT_KEY } from 'src/auth/jwt/jwt.constant';
import { JwtService } from 'src/auth/jwt/jwt.service';
import { UserService } from 'src/user/user.service';

@Injectable()
export class UploadMiddleware implements NestMiddleware {
  constructor(
    private readonly jwtService: JwtService,
    private readonly userService: UserService,
  ) {}
  async use(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) {
    try {
      //JWT_key is 'x-jwt'
      if (JWT_KEY in req.headers) {
        const token = req.headers[JWT_KEY];
        const decodedToken = this.jwtService.verify(token.toString());
        if (
          typeof decodedToken === 'object' &&
          decodedToken.hasOwnProperty('id')
        ) {
          const getUser = await this.userService.findUser({
            id: decodedToken.id,
          });
          if (getUser.sucess) {
            req['user'] = getUser.user;
          }
        }
      }
    } catch (e) {
      console.error(e);
    }
    next();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to do two things in one middleware. And that's not a good idea. Because when you need to check if the user is authenticated elsewhere, you need to copy and paste your code in this place. This is a bad pattern. Instead of that you should create separate **middleware** or **guard**(check nestjs doc about [guards](https://docs.nestjs.com/guards)). And this **guard** will check if user is authenticated or not. If it is then **guard** let request further. In other case **guard** throw Http exception 401 Unauthorized. As for file uploading you could use [multer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer). About file uploading check corresponding section of nestjs doc([how to upload file nestjs doc](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/file-upload)).

Comment: Thanks for the answer!. create separate middleware, why didn't i think of that...